# Chrome Extension - permission problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm building an extension.  One of the parts of the extension is to display an output from a VOIP server, using Javascript.

I'm using this one: https://github.com/CommandChannel/Mumble-Channel-Viewer/wiki

I've adjusted the content, so that the JS is inside my popup.js file, along with the var declared (so no inline JS).

The JSON output for the server is at: http://api.lethal-zone.eu/mumble/?view=json&serverId=1 which is modified to: http://api.lethal-zone.eu/mumble/?view=json&serverId=1?callback=? as the instructions say.

However, I'm getting the error:

```
Refused to load the script 'http://api.lethal-zone.eu/mumble/?view=json&serverId=1?callback=jQuery1910587204567855224_1369671235456&_=1369671235457' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".
```

Now I've done loads of looking around, and it seems JSONP callback isn't allowed if the domain isn't https:// (?)

My manifest has these permissions:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://*.lethal-zone.eu/*", 
    "https://*.lethal-zone.eu/*",
    "http://api.lethal-zone.eu/mumble/",
    "notifications",
    "storage"
],
```

Does anyone know how I could go about doing this without https? Or where I should be looking?

EDIT: Not much code to show, I have my div: `<div id="mumbleTree"></div>`, then the javascript from https://github.com/CommandChannel/Mumble-Channel-Viewer/blob/master/JavaScript/mumbleViewer.js is loaded, using `var mumbleChannelViewerJsonUri = "http://api.lethal-zone.eu/mumble/?view=json&serverId=1?callback=?";` as explained in these instructions: https://github.com/CommandChannel/Mumble-Channel-Viewer/wiki/Installation-instructions

Cheers

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to load a script from a url. You would need to modify your [`csp`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-remote-script) or include it locally.

Comment: Issue is: "Currently, we allow whitelisting origins with the following schemes: HTTPS, chrome-extension, and chrome-extension-resource." The URL I'm using isn't https, just http...

Comment: Also I can't include it locally, since every time the request is sent the data could be different.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Isn't really any to show, I add my mumbleTree div to the popup.html, then the javascript from the link but get the error shown above. Updated above anyway...

Comment: Alright, so I took a look at the code and I couldn't see a need for the callback. Just remove the `?callback=?` part and it should at least load the data correctly. You'll want to fix up the styling a bit though.

Comment: Ah well that does work, but only after the setInterval goes off, which is weird but I can work around that :) Cheers